# SingleFileGenerator / Run Custom Tool does not run for new vs2017 project type

Tags: visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-2019, single-file-generator

I have a SingleFileGenerator that works correctly for old-style Visual Studio C# projects, but not at all for the new-style VS2017 C# projects. I've added the new guid to registration attributes and to the packagedef, but still no joy.  For reference, this code generator acts on xml files with the extension .3schema, which is an xml file of our own invention...

```
[Guid("0BC6C7FE-28F7-4A64-A8F8-714FFC0F8FB4")]
[PackageRegistration(UseManagedResourcesOnly = true)]
[InstalledProductRegistration("TrilogySchemaGenerator", "Trilogy C# Schema Generator", "5.9")]
[CodeGeneratorRegistration(typeof(TrilogySchemaGenerator), "Trilogy C# Schema Generator", "{9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}", GeneratesDesignTimeSource = true)]
[CodeGeneratorRegistration(typeof(TrilogySchemaGenerator), "Trilogy C# Schema Generator", vsContextGuids.vsContextGuidVCSProject, GeneratesDesignTimeSource = true)]
[ProvideObject(typeof(TrilogySchemaGenerator))]
public class TrilogySchemaGenerator : BaseCodeGeneratorWithValidation // base class implements IVsSingleFileGenerator
{
     …
}
```

And the pkgdef:

```
[$RootKey$\Generators\{FAE04EC1-301F-11d3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}\.3schema]
@="TrilogySchemaGenerator"

[$RootKey$\Generators\{9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}\.3schema]
@="TrilogySchemaGenerator"
```

What step am I missing?  Is there an additional registration required?  Ideas of other things to try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've looked in the wrong place to solve my problem.  It was not a problem with my SingleFileGenerator at all! But if you are building a SingleFileGenerator, please look to this answer for details of how to register it properly:

[How to register "custom tool" with Visual Studio 2017 to make it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49819385/how-to-register-custom-tool-with-visual-studio-2017-to-make-it-work/)

I used this excellent tool to convert my old projects to the new VS2017. I highly recommend:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Project2015To2017.Migrate2017.Tool/

However, this tool does not deal well with custom build steps, of which my code generation is one. In my case, when I hand coded the custom build steps, I missed a reference to the noted line of XML:

```
  <ItemGroup>
       <XmlResource Include="Schema\T1TY2019.3schema">
     --> <Generator>TrilogySchemaGenerator</Generator> <--
         <LastGenOutput>T1TY2019.cs</LastGenOutput>
       </XmlResource>
     </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Hi friend, thanks for your sharing and please mark your reply as answer and that will help other community members who easier search this useful information, it just a reminder :)